# button keeps nudging when toggled with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the following code but when i click the menu button, all other menu itwms disappear as wanted, but the menu button nudges a bit to the right. also if i try to add a duration to the toggle, "over mij" becomes two lines.
can anyone give me help me?
-Max

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Homepagina </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- dit zijun de elementen van de menubalk: -->
    <div class="menuBar">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" id="button"> Over mij </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="button"> Hobbies </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="menuButton"> MENU </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="button"> Muziek </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="button"> Informatica </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- dit is de inhoud van de pagina: -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            hoi

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- dit is voor de menubalk acties: -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#menuButton").click(function(){
                $("[id=button]").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
    background-image: url(background.jpg); 
    margin: 0; /* reset de standard marges van de body -> geen randen links en rechts naast .menuBar div */
    text-align: center;
}

.menuBar {
    width: 100%;
}

.menuBar {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.menuBar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.menuBar ul li a {
    color: white;
    width: 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.menuBar a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#menuButton {
    font-size: 46px;
    position: relative;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    height: 650px;
    width: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 52%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 4.5px double white;
    border-bottom: 4.5px double white;
}
```

Comment: 1) You have duplicate IDs of "button".  IDs must be unique to work correctly.  2) Create an example of this at jsfiddle.net.  I have taken your code and it doesn't seem to create a button.

Comment: @TonyHinkle thats weird, using google chrome it works fine, but only the button nudges, but i cant seem to get a fiddle working.

Comment: OK--yes, for whatever reason this doesn't work in jsfiddle but I've got it in files now and opened in Chrome.  You might what to change the .menuBar CSS color to black as it is set to white and therefore is invisible.

Comment: @TonyHinkle yeah the background should be a wood texture but i didn't include it, but you can set the background-color in the body to black and it will do, but any idea on what's going on?

Comment: Do you want the menu items to be visible when the page first loads, or only after clicking on "Menu"?

Comment: @TonyHinkle only after clicking menu if that's possible, andthen it toggles when clicked again

Answer (score 0):

OK--you need to change `id="button"` to something different, because IDs need to be unique.  If you are just needing something to act as a selector, you can use a class in this instance.

Here are the changes to the HTML:

```
<li> <a href="#" class="myButton"> Over mij </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="myButton"> Hobbies </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" id="menuButton"> MENU </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="myButton"> Muziek </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="myButton"> Informatica </a> </li>
```

Next, add a toggle to the document ready to hide the menu items when the page loads, and add the animation time parameter:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //toggle myButton to hide them after the page loads.
        // If they are hidden before the page loads, the positions 
        // change a bit when they are toggled and that is what
        // is causing the main Menu button to move
        $(".myButton").toggle(300);

        $("#menuButton").click(function(){
            $(".myButton").toggle(300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Lastly, add a CSS rule to stop the menu items with two words from wrapping:

```
.myButton {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```